# Images in drawable of android

Tags: android, c++, security, image-processing, android-ndk

I am trying to hide my private key in an image by changing its pixel value at random locations and hiding this process by writing this code in c++ using ndk. so my questions are

1) Will android change drawable images when app is used in different screen size      thus erasing or corrupting my keys?

2) How hard it will be to write image processing code in ndk?

3) Is there any better and more secure place to store my keys? (Don't say db, key-value etc all can be hacked if phone is rooted)

Thank you.

Comment: Drawables in `drawable-nodpi` folder are never resized by Android. That being said, shipping private keys with your application is not recommended.

Comment: thanks, i do have to use private key to decrypt data from server, what else can i do?

Comment: Can't say without knowing your use case. But why do you need to encrypt the data if you are shipping the decryption key with your product anyway?

Comment: Your use case is not clear. How do you intend to decode the key in the end? If you have Java code that picks the pixel values from an image in drawable resources of your app, it can be easily reverse engineered.